# Exclude a sub-element of a toggling parent element from toggling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the form you can see here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28xv750r/20/)
Which is generated with this php code:

```
echo "<tr class='row0'onClick=\"$('#detailed_$voter[vid]').toggle();\"
style='cursor:pointer'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='getcheckz'/> </td>
<td>$rows_num</td> <td
align=\center\">$voter[time]<td align=\center\">$user[username]<td
align=\center\">$voter[email]<td align=\center\">$voter[ip]<td
align=\center\">$valid</td><td>$ccc</td></tr> ";
```

When someone clicks an element from the table, a hidden div is displayed that shows more Information about the user.
The form plus the script is working properly.
I added the checkbox element at the start of the table, so someone could check and delete records.
The problem is that the script targets the whole `<tr>` ( you can check the fiddle i prepared) , so when i click the checkbox the #detailed_ div popups. I need to exclude the div from toggling when the user clicks the checkbox.

Im a newbie on jquery so via API's and tutorials i tried some scripts like:

1)

```
    onClick=\"if ($(this) != $('.getcheckz')) { $('#detailed_$voter[vid]').toggle();}\"
```

2)

```
    onClick=\" toggledyo(detailed_$voter[vid]); \"

    function toggledyo(id) {
    $('#id').toggle();
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.getcheckz').click(function() {
  var checker = $("input[id^='#detailed_']").each(function() {
   if (checker.is(":visible")) {
    checker.toggle();
 // if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
 //  $(this).toggle();
}
});
});
});
```

I think im kinda near on the solution and i must do something wrong with the syntax, could someone Help me find out what is the error ?Hope i was clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. in fiddle, not even the first script works ! i created it so you can have a better glance of the Output.

Comment: do not use onclick on tr inline but create a $('tr').click(function() { etc... you can exclude subelement with not i suppose, search on google for "jquery onclick not child"

Comment: I won't read your code, please clean it. YOU MUST use {} for arrays in a double quoted string and quotes to access value ! => `"Oh my {$voter['username']}!"`

Comment: You really dont need to read the php code at all, posted it just to show that the id is dynamic , and changes every time ;)